# timer C# stop tick after few hours?

Tags: c#, timer

i have set timer to check for website  as follow:

```
bool stopped = true;

 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           timer1.Stop();

           if (!stopped)
           webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");

       }
```

but after few hours the timer stop tick? any help please to make timer not stopped! and if stopped force it to start again. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Your code says `timer1.Stop()` this will stop the timer. Remove that line and the timer wont stop.

Comment: Sorry for not clarify my point, I try to make timer work on schedule to check for website. is there better way to do that plz? thank you for your comment.

Comment: It depends on how far out you are trying to schedule and if you want the timer to be running always. Either break out the timed task in to a separate program and run it with the windows Task Scheduler or use the [reactive extensions library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) to get easy to work with long running timers. Please add more details what you are trying to do and what behavior you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start a timer at exactly 00:12:00am do some processing time and then restart the timer you just need to calculate the difference between Now and the next 00:12:00am time slot such as.

```
   static Timer timer;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    setup_Timer();
}

static void setup_Timer()
{
    DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime oneAmTime = new DateTime(nowTime.Year, nowTime.Month, nowTime.Day, 0, 12,0, 0);

    if (nowTime > oneAmTime)
    oneAmTime = oneAmTime.AddDays(1);

double tickTime = (double)(oneAmTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
timer = new Timer(tickTime);
timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
timer.Start()
}

static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    //process code..
   setup_Timer();
}
```

Hope it  clears your doubt.

Comment: Thank you very much it's working like a charm. one question, is it possible to modify it by let timer work every 20 second and restart once enable the timer. Thank you again, bless you.

Comment: @Brss82 You can use timer1.Enabled = true; and timer1.Start();
For setting the timer you can do like this :
' Sets the timer interval to 5 seconds.
        myTimer.Interval = 5000 //make it 20000 for 20 sec
        myTimer.Start()

Comment: Should i add timer1.Enabled = true; and timer1.Start(); Timer1.Interval = 5000 to setup_timer()? please advice? i appreciate your help in-advance. Thank you

Comment: Timer.Start:This does the same thing as setting Enabled to true. so you need not add both . Just give 
     timer1.Start(); Timer1.Interval = 5000

Comment: And dont give timer.Stop() at the beginning.Give it after you complete the use of timer

Comment: I think you can use the PingNetwork function that I have posted for checking the connection and also give the timer to check the connection or perform the functions at regular intervals . Hope you got an idea now :)  and please upvote if my other answer have also helped you :)

Comment: Yes indeed it's helpful sire. Should i removed from timer_Elapsed? where should i put it please.

Comment: No..You dont need to remove that.But if you dont want to stop the timer at any point you can remove that function.
The upvote can be done by pressing the up arrow above the '0' if you find the answer useful :)

Comment: I did, but it said: Vote up requires 15 reputation. what should i do? i will follow your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get the ques clearly. Do you want to check the availability of the site at regular intervals?If so you can try this

```
public bool PingNetwork(string hostNameOrAddress)
    {
        bool pingStatus = false;

        using (Ping p = new Ping())
        {
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            int timeout = 120;

            try
            {
                PingReply reply = p.Send(hostNameOrAddress, timeout, buffer);
                pingStatus = (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                pingStatus = false;
            }
        }

        return pingStatus;
    }
```

And inside button click

```
 private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(PingNetwork("www.google.com"))
        MessageBox.Show("Network Available");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Network Not Available");

    }
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: How to apply above code in webbrowser C# with timer plz? i used timer to tick each 20sec to navigate my site to keep my site alive, if session expired then will login programmatic, so i face timer stop tick! thank you very much.

Comment: All what i'm looking for, is to keep my site navigate by using timer programmatic to keep it a live... thank you all again for your positive post...

Comment: Well..you can give this code in the Page Load to check each time if the page is available.If you want to use timer then i have given the codes below. hope it helps you and clears your doubt!